# Relation between Oracle session and connection pool

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, connection, websphere

Let me explain the set up first.

We have an oracle server running on a 2GB RAM machine. The Db instance has the init parameter "sessions" set to 160.

We have the application deployed on Websphere 6.1. The connection pool settings is Min 50 and Max 150.

When we run Load test on 40 Users (concurrent, using jMeter), everything goes fine.
But when we increase the concurent users to Beyond 60, Oracle throws and exception that it is out of sessions.

We checked the application for any connection leaks but could not find any.

So does it mean that the concurrency of 40 is what this setup can take ? Is increasing the Oracle sessions/process the only way to obtain higher concurrency ?

How exactly are the DB sessions and Connection in the Connection pool related ? In my understanding, the connections cannot exceed the sessions and so setting the Max Connection pool to more than sessions may not really matter. Is that correct ?

Comment: You might want to consider putting this on serverfault.

Comment: This is totally programming related unfortunately.

Comment: @Terry - yes, but an Oracle DBA would probably have more insight about this than your average programmer.

Comment: Can you post the exact ORA error code?  Oracle can multiplex several sessions over one physical connection.  If the connection pool is just trying to open new sessions on existing physical connections, then you may be hitting the max sessions on a connection, not the max sessions the database can support.  Is the connection pool a custom one, or provided through Websphere?

Comment: ERROR code is 
ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded

Comment: Still confused why people use connections pool but not session pool

Answer (score 4):

Metalink gives the following advice about the SESSIONS parameter:

> Recursive sessions are an essential part of the normal functioning of the
>   RDBMS. It is impossible to identify
>   every circumstance that would require
>   such sessions, but in general, if a
>   user-initiated operation requires the
>   manipulation of data dictionary
>   objects, then recursive sessions may
>   get created. To take a simple example,
>   say you create a table while logged in
>   as some ordinary user. Behind the
>   scenes this has to insert rows into
>   obj$, tab$ etc which are owned by the
>   SYS user. Since a normal user would
>   have no privilege to insert into these
>   objects, a recursive session is
>   created which logs in as SYS.
>
> ### Solution:
>
> Increase the SESSIONS parameter.
>
> Recommendation is to preserve 50% of
>   the SESSIONS value for recursive
>   sessions. So, for example if it is
>   expected to have 30 client sessions
>   open, then set the SESSIONS parameter
>   to 60.

So, depending on what websphere and your user process are doing this could partially explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

My v$session contains 30 entries, 4 of which have a username (one of which is a background job).

If you've got background processes (eg batch jobs), they could be chewing up sessions.

But it could be that you are simply running out of memory. 2GB seems a bit low for a conneection pool of 50 sessions. Assuming Oracle 10g, you're RAM is divided into shared (SGA) and process (PGA). Say you've got 1.5GB for SGA, that leaves 500MB for all the sessions. If sessions grab 10MB each, you'll hit your limit around 50 sessions.

In reality, 
1. You'll have some other 'stuff' running on the box, so won't have a full 2GB available to Oracle

2. Your SGA may be smaller or larger
3. You may be on 11g and letting Oracle allocate PGA and SGA out a single pool
4. You may be using PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET (letting Oracle guess at the PGA settings based on the number of sessions) or setting memory limits yourself.
5. You may have some memory hungry processes that chew up stuff

PS. Does the 2GB mean you are on Windows ?

Comment: It is a windows box. 2GB RAM is the total RAM avbl.
We are on Oracle 10g R2.
Max SGA Size is 652 MB
Aggregate PGA Target is 24 MB
Current PGA Allocated is 72 MB
Max PGA ever allocated is 247 MB

Answer (score 1):

Are all your connections using the same user account?  If so, you might want to check to see if you have a per-user session limit for that user account.

Also, are you licensed for more than 40 connections?  (Check if you have LICENSE_MAX_SESSION set in your parameter file)

Comment: the parameter license_max_sessions is set to zero.
sessions = 170
sessions_max_open_files = 10
shared_server_sessions - not set to any value.

Answer (score 1):

The session pool is client-side driven.  It doesn't know (or control) how many sessions the database will allow.

You should look on the server to determine the actual number of connections that are allowed and set the session pool number based on what the server will allow.

Your connection pool should not use all of the connections allowed.  This will let other IDs connect.  If you have an application using USER_1, you'd set the connection pool to use some amount of the allowed connections, but leave enough connections for... Oh, say DBA to log in.

-- Edit --
Processes are probably runing out before your connection pool maxes out.

```
SQL> show parameter processes

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
processes                            integer     40
```

This is the total # of processes allowed
Now see how many are already used - many of them are background procs, you'd never think of.

```
SQL> select count(*) from v$process;
```

Comment: I think he's set there - with a max pool size of 150 and a max of 160 sessions, he should have ~10 left over for other user connections.

Comment: I reduced the max pool size to 100. But still this problem occurs.