# Golang - many in use connections

Tags: database, oracle, go, connection, connection-pooling

#golang #oracle

Im trying to understand how the Max connection works. Basically I have this db configuration:

```golang
params.MinSessions = 5
params.MaxSessions = 6
params.SessionTimeout = 0
params.WaitTimeout = 5 * time.Second
params.SessionIncrement = 0
params.ConnClass = "GOLANGPOOL"

// Connect!
result, err := sql.Open("godror", params.StringWithPassword())
result.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
```

However I can see 242 connections using sql.DB.Stats:

```sh
DB Established Open Conn (use + idle): 242
DB Idle Conn: 0
DB In Use Conn: 242
DB Max Idle Closed: 766
DB Max Idle Time Closed: 0
DB Max Lifetime Closed: 0
DB Max Open Conn: 0
DB Wait Count: 0
DB Wait Duration (sec): 0
```

How is it possible? The limit shouldn't be 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle connections and sessions are different concepts.

> A connection is a network connection to the DB, while a session is an
> encapsulation of a user's interaction with the DB...

refering to [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=9MsOpXrElhUC&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=oracle+%22sessions+vs+connections%22&source=bl&ots=mBwnWKBDQl&sig=XPkoqteZ_B_C8NT1tHh4rS4UKwI&hl=en&ei=s2BCSoKFHI3SMNbyvMAH&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=oracle%20%22sessions%20vs%20connections%22&f=false), and [Relation between Oracle session and connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039637/relation-between-oracle-session-and-connection-pool).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using latest version of driver, https://github.com/godror/godror

```
sql.Open("godror", params.StringWithPassword()) 

implies standaloneConnection=0 setting.
```

The stats you are seeing is from go sql connection pool.  The go sql calls the  driver connect method which inturn tries to get connection from another pool (OCI maintains it due to setting standaloneConnection=0 ).

The max outbound connections hasn't exceeded the params.MaxSessions but its just the go sql connection counter

```
numOpen, ....
```

It is ideal you tune the go sql pool settings closer to another pool values so that the go routines just don't block.

You can check the OCI pool stats by using GetPoolStats()
method from godror.Conn and confirm the real number of maximum outbound connections. example here

```
https://github.com/godror/godror/blob/main/z_test.go
```

Answer (score 0):

> DB In Use Conn: 242
> DB Max Idle Closed: 766

The sum is almost 1000, like the value of this default

> poolMaxSessions=1000

I think you don’t have 242 simultaneous connections in use. You have a pull of connections and the database will limit the number of simultaneous sessions.

You should check how the sql package handles it (it is open source!) and how the specific driver handles it (also open source!) and if necessary open an issue on the driver project

https://github.com/godror/godror